# Convert int to int[]

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dataset and i am trying to get all the Ids of the datset into a datarow to finally save it in a int array. Its not working for me. It says `"Cannot implicitly convert from type int to int[]"`

```
Dataset ds = new BusinessLogic().Getsamples(MerchantID);

Datarow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];

int[] SampleID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]);
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Convert.ToInt32 returns a single int not an array of them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx

Comment: Are you trying to get a single ID (cast as a single int) or get ALL ID.  You code is part single, part multi.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to create a new int array and put the int in there.

```
int sampleID = new int[1];
sampleID[0] = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]);
```

I think this shorthand will work too:

```
int[] SampleID = new int[]{Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"])};
```

Comment: you beat me and identical so +1 to you

Comment: I can't see why this is actually a useful thing to do, to be honest. Why create a single-element array rather than just keeping the single value in its own variable? It's not like the array can be expanded later...

Answer (score 7):

Well yes. Look at this line:

```
int[] SampleID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]);
```

The right hand side is an `int` (the result of `Convert.ToInt32`) but you're trying to convert that into an *array*.

If you want *all* the IDs, I suggest you create a `List<int>` and iterate over the rows, calling `list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"])` for each row and then call `ToArray()` at the end if you really need to.

Alternatively, use LINQ - something like:

```
int[] ids = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(dr => dr.Field<int>("Id"))
                        .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

You're just getting out the one ID, I think you might have meant to loop through all the rows getting out all the IDs?

Maybe you want something like:

```
List<int> ids = new List<int>();
foreach(Datarow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    ids.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]));
}
int[] SampleID = ids.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's an array! Try:

```
int[] SampleID = new int[] {(int)dr["Id"]);
```