# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'int[]'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have declared my `int[]` as follows

`int[] iroleID = new int[] { };`

My code for getting the values from database and assigning to `iroleid` is as follows

```
if (oAuthenticate.getTaskID(out m_oDataSet1, "uspgetTaskID"))
{
  for (int iTaskid = 0; iTaskid < m_oDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.Count; iTaskid++)
  {
   iroleID = Convert.ToInt32(m_oDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows[iTaskid]["RoleID"].ToString());
   strTaskID = m_oDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows[iTaskid]["TaskID"].ToString();
   arrTaskID.Add(strTaskID);
   }
}
```

But i am getting an error as mentioned `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'int[]'` can any one help me

Comment: possible duplicate : [Convert int to int Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216493/convert-int-to-int)

Comment: Putting a `DataRow row = m_oDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows[iTaskid];` at the beginning of the loop code and referencing it instead of writing row access code each and every line keeps the doctor away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And no surprise here. Look at

```
iroleID = Convert.ToInt32(...);
```

`Convert.ToIn32` results in an `int` just like the compiler claims.
Either do something like:

```
if (oAuthenticate.getTaskID(out m_oDataSet1, "uspgetTaskID"))
{
    var iroleID = new int[m_oDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.Count];
    for (int iTaskid = 0; iTaskid < m_oDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.Count; iTaskid++)
    {
        iroleID[iTaskid] = Convert.ToInt32(m_oDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows[iTaskid]["RoleID"].ToString());
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

or rethink your algorithm.

PS: I can hardly tell you what exactly to do as you don't show what the purpose of `iRoleID` is.

Comment: Getting `Index was outside the bounds of the array.` if i use this

Comment: you sure you did use the new `int[m_oDataSet1...]` stuff?

Answer (score 1):

off course!

```
 iroleID = Convert.ToInt32(m_oDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows[iTaskid]["RoleID"].ToString());
```

`iroleID` is an `int` array; `Convert.ToInt32()` returns an int .
so:
-you must declare an `int` variable tu store `Convert.ToInt32()` value
or
-just add `Convert.ToInt32()` result to `iroleID` ( `iroleID.Add(Convert.ToInt32(...))` )

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can't just assign the `int` value to the `int[]` variable. Probably you need to add items to the collection. Change your `int[] iroleID = new int[] { };` to `List<int> iroleID = new List<int>();` and then change code to:

```
if (oAuthenticate.getTaskID(out m_oDataSet1, "uspgetTaskID"))
{
  for (int iTaskid = 0; iTaskid < m_oDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.Count; iTaskid++)
  {
   iroleID.Add(Convert.ToInt32(m_oDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows[iTaskid]["RoleID"].ToString()));
   strTaskID = m_oDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows[iTaskid]["TaskID"].ToString();
   arrTaskID.Add(strTaskID);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use indexing for the int array to assign a value, you can't assign an integer directly to an integer array.

```
iroleID[0] = Convert.ToInt32(m_oDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows[iTaskid]["RoleID"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
iroleID = Convert.ToInt32(m_oDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows[iTaskid]["RoleID"].ToString());
```

This would convert the RoleID columns value to an integer. You are taking this integer and trying to assign it to an integer array which of course is not possible. What exactly is your idea? If it is to populate a single array with all the IDs you can do the same as you did but assign it to a normal integer and then add that integer to a list or something.

You can also just use plain ADO.NET to retrieve all the values from that column and cast it to an List. That would be better.

Answer (score 0):

One problem has already been answered, you must add it to an array giving the position you want

```
iroleID[iTaskid] = Convert.ToInt32(m_oDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows[iTaskid]["RoleID"].ToString());
```

the other problem is, that you create an array. You must give the length of the array.

`int[] iroleID = new int[m_oDataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.Count];`