# Convert type int[] to int**

Tags: c#, .net, image

I'm playing with pixels in an image..

What i have:

```
int w; // width
int h; // height
unsafe private int **pData; // pixel data
```

i want to be able to set pData's height and width... so something like the following:

```
 pData = new int*[w]; 

 for(int x = 0; x<w; x++)
    pData = new int*[h];
```

this causes an error though ("cannot implicitly convert int[] to int**). How would i go about doing this in C#? I know this will work in C and C++...

I guess what i'm looking for is an equivalent to the above in C# ... as that is written in C++

Comment: Yes, I know the difference... but i'm using C# within the .Net framework.... so i put C#.Net...

Comment: I don't quite get what you are trying to do but i am pretty sure that there is no need to use pointers here...

Comment: Is pdata going to be passed into a Pinvoke method? Is that why you're using pointers?

Comment: basically, i'm creating my own image and setting the colours myself. i'm then passing this to a saveimage method. the point of the program is to save the image (without using "Image.Save()") the point in this specific method is to set the size...

Comment: please take this url
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632302/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-int-to-int

Comment: @BlueMonster Modified my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you just want a pixel grid?

In C# you could just use multidimensional [arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx) or an array of arrays, e.g.

```
private int[,] pixelData = new int[w, h];

// (Might have confused some variables here)
private int[][] pixelData = new int[w][];
for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) pixelData[i] = new int[h];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't initialize buffers in this way. You can do this:

```
class MyImage
{
    Int32[] _Buffer;
    Int32* _Pointer;
    GCHandle _Handle;

    public MyImage() {
        _Buffer = new Int32[w * h];
        _Handle = GCHandle.Alloc(_Buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        _Pointer = (Int32*)_Handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer();
    }
}
```

But don't do this, this will prevent the GC from doing it's work. Better use [fixed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx) each time you want to access your buffer.

### Images

When dealing with images you should use Int32[] because of the fact that Int32[,] is slower ( see msdn ). You can simply create and modify the image the following way:

```
Int32[] buffer = new Int32[width * height];
```

Access:

```
buffer[x + (width * y)] ...
```

Comment: Answered the question, *and* gave the sensible advice. +1

Comment: @AndrewBarber Thanks, i think i work to much because i answer the question without looking at any help or code...hope it's correct...